# how to config Jenkins container run maven container to use a proxy

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins

all,
   As i try to use Jenkins to build-a-java-app-with-maven (https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/).
   I have a problem, my environment accessing network have to use private proxy.
My Jenkins run in a container and when I use the below pipeline, the Jenkins container will pull maven image and maven run in the container but because the environment has a proxy, maven container was not config to use a proxy, so maven can not download dependencies.

Can anyone give me help on how to let the maven container to use a proxy? thanks

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine' 
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [withEnv](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/) to set `proxy_host` environment variable?

Also take a look at:

- https://git.oneapi-project.net/microgateway/plugins/backend-jwt/commit/7287ff0516d5c9a91f5f34b37ec2d6e80350f5c7
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43077
- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy

Answer (score 0):

First : to use a corporate proxy with Maven, you need to configure it in your `settings.xml` (see [Configuring a proxy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) in the Maven documentation).

Second : in a pipeline running in a container, you can do this in many ways. Here are some of them :

1. Given you are mapping `/root/.m2:/root/.m2`, you could simply put your `settings.xml` in `/root/.m2`. This assumes you're executing Jenkins as `root`, which I highly discourage in production, for security reasons.

   If you're executing Jenkins as a different user, you have to adapt the volume mapping accordingly.
2. Map your `settings.xml` file as a volume in your container and tell Maven to use it, like so :

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'maven:3-alpine' 
      args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 -v /path/to/settings.xml:/my/settings.xml:ro' 
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') { 
      steps {
        sh 'mvn -s /my/settings.xml -B -DskipTests clean package' 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. Store the `settings.xml` file as a credential in Jenkins and use it with [`withCredentials`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables), which can make sense if your settings.xml contains passwords :

```
  ...
  steps {
    withCredentials([
      file(credentialsId: 'maven-settings', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')
    ]) {
      sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS -B -DskipTests clean package'
    }
  }
  ...
```

4. Instead of using the official Maven image `maven:3-alpine`, build a custom image containing your `settings.xml` file and use it in your pipeline.